# In laravel, how to use select() and get key and value as object like what eloquent returns

Tags: laravel, object, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm new to laravel and want to get some properties like an object instead of string
this is what select() gives me:
`foo: "bar",`
this is what I want
`foo: { bar: "some value" },`

Basically like what eloquent models do, it returns a nested property. I want to achieve that with `select` after `join` of course.

Or may be a method to manipulate the outcome instead of just using `get()` (without `paginate`).

I want to get some properties like an object instead of string
this is what select() gives me:
`foo: "bar",`
this is what I want
`foo: { bar: "some value" },`

Basically like what eloquent models do, it returns a nested property. I want to achieve that with `select` after `join` of course.

Comment: You can use `selectRaw` method of DB Facade and `json_object` of mysql, `$results = DB::table('users')->join('user_device_infos', 'users.id', '=', 'user_device_infos.user_id')->selectRaw('users.email, json_object("fcm", user_device_infos.fcm) as fcm')->get();
` and the results will be something like this:         `"email": "allen71@romaguera.com",
        "fcm": "{"fcm": "users_fcm"}"`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired output with select after join, you can use the DB::raw() method to construct a raw SQL expression that selects and aliases the nested property:

```
$results = DB::table('table1')
             ->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.table1_id')
             ->select('table1.id', DB::raw('JSON_OBJECT("bar", table2.foo) AS foo'))
             ->get();
```

In the above example, JSON_OBJECT() is a MySQL function that constructs a JSON object from the specified key-value pairs. The resulting JSON object is aliased as foo and will be returned as a nested property in the query results.

If you want to manipulate the outcome further, you can use the map() method on the query results to apply custom transformations to each row:

```
$results = DB::table('table1')
             ->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.table1_id')
             ->select('table1.id', DB::raw('JSON_OBJECT("bar", table2.foo) AS foo'))
             ->get()
             ->map(function ($row) {
                 $row->foo = json_decode($row->foo);
                 return $row;
             });
```

In the above example, the map() method is used to decode the JSON object in the foo property of each row, effectively converting it from a string to a nested object. You can apply any other transformations you need inside the callback function passed to map().